Need to change password but its asking for a root password to make changes
I'm trying to change my password on Ubuntu, and it keeps saying give root password for maintenance. Does anyone know what to do?


Why are you in recovery mode here? Changing your own password should not require anything other than the passwd command from a regular user terminal

I watched a yt video and it told me to do that, to add more context im using virtual box i dont know if that makes a difference or not. How do i get to the terminal?

This question is similar to: Unable to change user password in Ubuntu 12.10. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Login to your current desktop
Open Terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T or executing it on the Applications menu.
Then on the terminal, type passwd and hit enter.
Enter your current password,
then enter your new password,
again re-enter your new password.
There should be a message after changing the password saying Your password has been changed.
Hope this helps...
